# How to Select a data block's user in outliner?

Tags: selection-tools, linked-data, data-blocks

[image]

How to Select data block's user in outliner??

Nothing happens with my gesture on the gif.

And how to I know users in other scenes?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after looking online and trying to acomplish the same thing with python, I found that it has not yet been implemented. This can be seen if you right click on "Actions" just above what you were clicking on, and click "Select" or "Select Linked", Blender tells you this has not been implemented. It appears the devs forgot to add this to sub-items.

Basically, the button's there but it can't be done yet.

Comment: Oh,,,i never knew the official released Blender has featureless buttons...

Do you know how to suggest this to devs?

Comment: @J.SungHoon Yeah, it's generally obscure stuff like this though, but can be a little annoying. I imagine they all ready know about it. Considering it's in the main build that means it is in the pipeline, should happen soon.

Comment: It's such a relief that.
So, let me ask you more about the original question.

Do you know the easiest way to find users of datablock?

Action data in the example GIF isn't The only problem.

It is not easy to grasp the datablock of material, texture, image etc. in a complex scene completely.

Examples are 'img.png.001, img.png.002, img.png.003 ...' which are not used for work but have users.